discord.py аватарка по айди
У меня есть база данных, где есть айди участников сервера. Каким методом можно отправить аватарку пользователя по его айди?

Сначала получаем самого участника сервера по айди, а потом берем из найденного member аватарку:
for guild in bot.guilds:
    member = guild.get_member(айди_участника)
    # А дальше получаем аватарку: member.avatar
    return


Спаибо большое!

Я сделал такой код:
for guild in bot.guilds:         memb = guild.get_member(owner_id)         await memb.avatar.save(filename3)         return
Но команда зависает и не прогружает код команды дальше. Что можно сделать? (Сорри за табуляцию, так вставило:()
